# firemonkey + xcode, mixed code

Tags: objective-c, delphi, delphi-xe2

Using Delphi XE2 we can  export sources into xcode and compile them with free pascal compiller. But all examples i'v ever seen dont modify .pas files in xcode, just export and run.

I wonder if I could add any delphi units or libraries into Objective C application and compile them together? How to include .pas unit into .xcodeproj?

I wish to port delphi application to iOS, exporting all project is impossible, it seems a good idea to make a GUI for iOS in native ObjectiveC and import logic and methods from delphi units. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Since Delphi XE2 is using the [Free Pascal Compiler](http://freepascal.org/) when targeting iOS, you can use any programming technique of FPC.

In fact, if you do not need FireMonkey, and prefer using native User Interface, you do not need Delphi XE2 at all!

You can use the free FPC to compile your application from XCode.

The best reference web site is http://web.me.com/macpgmr/ObjP

In particular, ["Developing with Objective Pascal" articles](http://web.me.com/macpgmr/ObjP/Xcode4/) is exactly what you are looking for:

- Develop the UI within XCode;
- Use FPC to code your business logic in Pascal;
- For both Max OSX and iOS.

See just the [introduction page](http://web.me.com/macpgmr/ObjP/Xcode4/ObjP_Part1.html), and I suspect you'll be amazed, like I was.

From my POV, the "Object Pascal" paradigm used with FPC (i.e. object pascal "dialect", which can coexist with the default object pascal code) is more advanced, lightweight and integrated than the interface-based "plumbing" of Delphi XE2 compiler (with on-the-fly marshalling using RTTI). This is perhaps a matter of taste...

Comment: Would you like to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159414/using-delphi-version-of-hyphenation-algorithm